# String Input (Only outputs the first word said)

Tags: java, oop, java-7

I'm trying to make a piece of code that will yell out anything I input.

So the command is 'yell'

I want to be able to type 'yell (whatever i want here)' and it will yell it out. I've managed to get this working with a help of a friend. But for some reason it will only yell the first word that's been output. So I can't type a sentence because it will only say the first word of a sentence.

Here's the piece of code, I hope you can help.

```
case "npcyell":
    for (NPC n : World.getNPCs()) {
        if (n != null && Utils.getDistance(player, n) < 9) {
            String sentence = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < cmd.length; i++) {
                sentence = sentence + " " + cmd[i];
            }
            n.setNextForceTalk(new ForceTalk("[Alert] "
                    + Utils.getFormatedMessage(sentence)));
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: have you tried checking what your "cmd.length" is in the for-loop? the problem might be in another part of your code. And correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be "length()" instead of "length"? (I'm not that in to java)

Comment: It's not length() because length is a static variable. But you're right about the cmd.length value. Try putting before your for loop the following line: "System.out.println("CMD LENGTH: " + cmd.length"); Can you tell me how much that number is?

Comment: What type is `cmd`? If it's an String array you may want to start the loop with index 0, i.e: `for (int i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++)`. Also, print out cmd.length and see what the value is.

Comment: @spaniard he starts at 1 because he doesn't want his command to be part of his sentence ^_^ e.g. "yell this is my sentence"

Comment: looks like cmd is a array of strings?

Comment: the problem is in your cmd. also, for (NPC n : World.getNPCs()) { will use the same cmd throughout the loop

Comment: A wild guess is that there's some mistake in how you assign cmd's value. I assume it's some kind of string splitting going on; perhaps some argument is off. Can you show us how you create/split cmd?

Comment: I'm not that good with java, I'm learning and don't really know what you mean. If someone could teamview me to help me or skype me or something try and help solve this problem. :)

Comment: @Jack: At some point before the code you supplied, there should be one or more lines starting with "String[] cmd =" or "cmd =" (or similar).  If you could copy and paste those lines into a comment or the original question, it would probably simplify things for us.

Comment: @Jack: Basically, from the code supplied it looks like cmd[] is an array of Strings which contains only 2 strings. cmd[0] appears to be the command itself and cmd[1] appears to be the "sentence" that you are outputting. However, you are expecting there to be more than just two Strings (cmd[2], cmd[3] ... cmd[n]). We need to see where cmd[] is created, so we can tell you why it only contains 2 Strings.

Comment: @Jack: In case you execute `yell "this is a sentence"` you will only have 2 elements in the array, cmd[0]=yell; cmd[1]="this is a sentence". If you want to split the second argument you can use this: `// given that cmd[1] contains "this is a sentence."`
`String[] words = cmd[1].split(" ");`
`for (String word : words) {`
`System.out.println(word);`
`}`

Comment: `code`public static boolean processAdminCommand(final Player player,
   String[] cmd, boolean console, boolean clientCommand) {
  if (clientCommand) {
   switch (cmd[0]) {

Comment: Okay, it would seem that the culprit is in another method. From where is processAdminCommand called and where is the cmd parameter calculated?

Comment: @Jack: Somewhere in you code you must be calling processAdminCommand(...) and passing a String[] object as the second argument. It is the creation of _that string object_ that we need to see.

Comment: if (player.getRights() >= 2
    && processAdminCommand(player, cmd, console, clientCommand))
   return true;

Comment: @Jack.: Yes, and where does cmd come from?

Comment: @Jack: Again, you are just showing us cmd being passed to the method, rather than where it is created. Somewhere you must have a line like `String[] cmd = something`.

Comment: @Jack: You know what? Only getting a tiny glimpse of the code and then waiting for the next one is going nowhere fast. Could you just copy all code related to command input and processing into a pastebin or something? If we have all relevant code in front of us instead of asking for bits and pieces, we could probably solve your problem in a minute or something.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hwVCDMVz

Comment: Hm. Everything looks good in terms of cmd. If so, the problem would either have to be in the variable "command", the method "setNextForceTalk" or "getFormatedMessage". *shrug*

Comment: Well, can I have some help please.

Comment: @Jack Have you tried adding debug printouts to print the `command` variable that is being passed to the `processCommand` method? That would be a good first approach to verify whether the `command` variable really contains what you expect...

Comment: I'm a beginner, no idea what you're saying.

Comment: Could you show exactly how you execute the command?

Comment: I fixed it, I just removed the formatted message thing. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did something similar a while ago. You said that you wanted to be able to say "yell(text)" and have it output whatever the text was. I have a different way of implementing it than you do, but the general result is the same, but it can be adapted to however you are using it in this context. This is also assuming that you are running this program as a console project only. if not change the scanner with whatever you are using to input text into and replace the text assignment to 
`text = textInputArea.getText().toString();` 
and change the output statement to `System.out.println(text.getText().toString().substring(6,text.getText().toString().length() - 1));`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = s.nextLine();
if (text.startsWith("yell(") && text.endsWith(")")){
    System.out.println(text.substring(6,text.length() - 1));
}
```

I hope this works for you. And I honestly hope that this is adaptable towards the program you are making.